# WSO2 IOTS won't register a new Android device

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm doing a proof of concept getting WSO2 IOTS up and running to manage Android devices. After working through other issues, I've got the device management console working as expected. I can create users, etc.

When I enroll my first Android device, I am able to install the agent and configure the server. On the Android device I get an error "Incorrect login information. Please try again." I am using the admin user with the correct password.

In the http access log I can see the Android hit the server and work gets done. If I use incorrect credentials, there is an HTTP 401 response and the Android never returns from the "Authenticating" dialog box.

```
192.168.1.137 - - [04/Feb/2017:21:05:52 -0600] "POST /services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService HTTP/1.1" 200 1269 "-" "Axis2"
192.168.1.137 - - [04/Feb/2017:21:05:52 -0600] "POST /services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService HTTP/1.1" 200 1261 "-" "Axis2"
192.168.1.137 - - [04/Feb/2017:21:05:52 -0600] "POST /services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService HTTP/1.1" 200 1279 "-" "Axis2"
192.168.1.137 - - [04/Feb/2017:21:05:52 -0600] "POST /services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService HTTP/1.1" 200 1279 "-" "Axis2"
192.168.1.182 - - [04/Feb/2017:21:05:52 -0600] "POST /api-application-registration/register HTTP/1.1" 201 91 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ), Android"
192.168.1.182 - - [04/Feb/2017:21:05:52 -0600] "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-T580 Build/MMB29K)"
```

I can't find any other errors in the other logs that indicate what's causing the device registration fail, or even what call is failing. Any ideas on where to look to figure out what's happening and how to get my device registered?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Check this comment - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-784?focusedCommentId=96183&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-96183

Comment: what is the IP address you provided to connect with the server?. Inorder to debug enable wire logs (uncomment log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG in core/repository/conf/log4j.properties file)

Comment: The IP address of the server is 192.168.1.137 and the IP address of the Android tablet is 192.168.1.182. I provided 192.168.1.137:9763 to the Android agent. Am connecting with the server based on the http logs. Also getting a different response from incorrect credential (HTTP 401) and the behavior on the Android agent is different. I will enable debug on the wire logs and see what I can learn. From the EMM issue id in the URL it looks like the recommendation is to recompile the Android agent with logging. Will try that next as it will take more time.

Comment: In EMM default port was used to be 9763 but from IoTS 3.0.0 the port is changed to 8082. Now all the devices apis are published to the gateway.

Comment: Agreed with @exterminator. and if you are using carbon.super tennant please keep the domain field empty when logging from the device.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. It looks like the documentation changed to reflect that the port should be 8280 (not 8082). Changing the server to be :8280 has me successfully retrieving my policy and on my way. Thank you for the help.